# Wordpress conflicting anchor tags (menu and slider)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I can't seem to understand how to fix my conflict with the anchor tags, I guess both the menu and slider uses the anchor tags ("#") and that's the reason the menu wont open up at all.

I'm using this slider for my Wordpress website:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/02/26/full-width-image-slider/

I don't know if I would have to post code since it's just a conflict?

Comment: please provide some code. I don't understand where exactly you see a conflict?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
 <div id="fwslider" class="fwslider">
        <ul>
            <li>
              <a class="slider" href="javascript:void(0)">
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/1.jpg" alt="img01"/>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="slider" href="javascript:void(0)">
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/2.jpg" alt="img02"/>
              </a>
            </li>     
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding classes to the anchor tags

```
<div id="cbp-fwslider" class="cbp-fwslider">
<ul>
    <li><a class="slider" href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="img01"/></a></li>
    <li><a class="slider" href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="img02"/></a></li>
    <li><a class="slider" href="#"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="img03"/></a></li>
    <li><a class="slider" href="#"><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="img04"/></a></li>
    <li><a class="slider" href="#"><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="img05"/></a></li>
</ul>
```